# I'm confused with the use of 'every time'

Tags: grammaticality

> My heart beats every time.

I'm confused with the use of the phrase 'every time'. Please explain it to me.The sentence is taken from a school test. Although I know the sentence is not complete, I can't explain it to others. So I ask for your help.

> Finish each sentence in such a way that it means exactly the same as the sentence that is given:
>   My heart beats every time.
>   There is no time _________________.

The answer the examiner wants is "There is no time that my heart does not beat".

Comment: Thein lwin I what do you think of my explanation on the phrase 'every time?

Comment: @theinIwin If this sentence is from a school test, what is the question on the test? You don't provide us with any information. Also, several dictionaries provide a clear definition of the phrase _every time._ It is a very simple phrase with a very simple meaning. What dictionaries have you consulted? Finally, the sentence is not meaningful in English. If your heart does NOT beat every time, you are dead!

Comment: @P.E.Dant. I'm still alive as my heart is beating. What I'd like to know is whether the use of 'every time' in this sentence is grammatically correct and meaningful. I don't need to provide you with any more information.

Comment: @theinIwin It is grammatical, but it has no meaning in this sentence other than "I am not dead". What was the question on your test? Without at least that information, I don't think the question will be reopened. (Have you consulted a dictionary?)

Comment: @theinlwin You are almost there! What is the "sentence that is given"? That sentence begins with "There is no time..."

Comment: Yes. That sentence begins with "There is no time....".

Comment: @theinlwin I regret to tell you either that the teacher who wrote this test does not understand English, or that you have copied the question inaccurately. I say this because there is no way in which a sentence in English beginning with _"My heart beats every time"_ could have a meaning even remotely similar to that of the sentence _"There is no time that my heart does not beat."_ (It is unfortunate, but unfortunately not uncommon, that some who pretend to be "teachers" of English do not in fact speak or understand it themselves.)

Comment: @P.E.Dant. Thanks a lot for your patient explanation.

Comment: You MUST copy exactly what the question asks. I bet with every heartbeat  that the question included a gapped answer, e.g. "There is ___ time that my heart ____ ____ beat. "

Answer (score 1):

Every time what? The statement is confusing because absent other information the logical inferred complement to it would be a redundancy:

> My heart beats every time it beats.

The construction could certainly be completed differently:

> My heart beats every time I see your face.
>   My heart beats every time the clock ticks.
>   My heart beats every time my pacemaker shocks it.

But without additional information not supplied, the statement is essentially meaningless.

Note that "every time" in the latter three examples simply means "in concert with" or "at the same time as" and implies a connection between two events.

Answer (score 1):

Everytime means "All the time and always or 'whenever something happens'. Everytime isn't the correct, so, it should be written as two separate words: every time. For some examples:

1.we can't keep calling the doctor every time you get a headache.

2.you don't need to remind me to do the dishes every time.

3.Every time we breath,we inhale pollutants.

The phrase 'every time' can be used in many ways:

> To mean 'throughout a specific period of time:
>
> All the time through December and january,jane held down two jobs.
>
> To mean 'all times,continuously.
>
> your blood keeps flowing all the time.
>
> To mean 'repeatedly,habitually
>
> she keeps a handkerchief in her hand all the time.

The phrase 'Every time' can be used in a situation that often happens,especially a negative situation:

> Every time I ask her to help out, she gets all angry and defensive!
>
> Every time we eat here,they screw up our order.
>
> Every time he cooks,he leaves greases spattered all oves the stovetop.

Don't be confused with the word "everytime", it's not an acceptable word http://www.dictionarykiwi.com/t/whats-the-difference-between-every-time-and-everytime/99

Comment: @ yubraj sharma, Thanks for your explanation. It helps me.